# Where is the boot image in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I installed Nero on my PC and when selecting DVD (boot) the bootable image textbox is already filled. With my naivety, I changed this path and need to get the original path but cannot find where the .ima file exists (or whichever boot file I need from Vista to make a bootable DVD).

Can anyone explain where I can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know specifically, but [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is a great searcher. Just search for .ima and it'll give you the path.